# For loop to linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am absolute beginner with Linq. I have a for loop that I want to convert to Linq statement. This loop is basically performing a hit test on rectangles which are hitting an edge. It is excluding a rectangle.

```
private List<Rectangle> GetTouchingRects(List<Rectangle> rects, Edge edgeToCheck, Rectangle exclude)
{
    List<Rectangle> hittingRects = new List<Rectangle>();

    foreach (Rectangle rect in rects)
    {
        if (rect != exclude)
        {
            if (rect.Touch(edgeToCheck))
            {
                hittingRects.Add(rect);
            }
        }
    }

    return hittingRects;
}
```

I can write very basic Linq queries, but I have no idea on this one. I am mainly confused in how to check the exclusion check and how to perform the hit test.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why does this NEED to be converted to LINQ?

Comment: Why does any code needs to be converted to LINQ?

Comment: LINQ is a tool used to solve problems.  So is a foreach-loop.  You've already solved it quite well using one method.  Why change it (other than self-exploration)?

Comment: I want to learn how to convert loops to LINQ. I am writting a code that is getting bigger and messier. It is part of rectangle stacking, clipping, and contour tracing problem. So may be LINQ can help me simplify the loops and make code more readable. Thanks for your feedback though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're basically just filtering twice. You could do that with two `Where` calls, or one:

```
return rects.Where(rect => rect != exclude)
            .Where(rect => rect.Touch(edgeToCheck))
            .ToList();
```

Or:

```
return rects.Where(rect => rect != exclude && rect.Touch(edgeToCheck))
            .ToList();
```

Use whichever you find more readable. You *could* write this as a query expression:

```
return (from rect in rects
        where rect != exclude && rect.Touch(edgeToCheck)
        select rect).ToList();
```

... but that seems a bit pointless to me. It's worth being comfortable with both kinds of syntax in LINQ.

Comment: I can only accept an answer in 8 min :)

Comment: I think the second one is better. I am not sure how Linq works. In first one two where clauses means, it perform the check in two passes?

Comment: @user2483744: Well, one pass with two checks for each item. Imagine it's a conveyor-belt with quality control people throwing things away. You can either have one person checking for two aspects of each item, or two people each checking for one.

Answer (score 3):

Jon's explanation was great, but I will also say [`Resharper`](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) was a great tool for me when I was first learning `LINQ`.

It has a cool feature that will allow you to convert a code block into `LINQ` (if it knows how to).

For your case it would look like this:

[image]

And the output would look like Jon's first answer:

[image]

This will get you started, but like anything, practice is what will make you better over time.

Comment: This is the second time I have mentioned Resharper on SO. I promise I don't work for JetBrains hah.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have downloaded Resharper, but when I install it, end throws the error 2755 and quits. Any idea?

Comment: @user2483744 Hopefully you have been able to fix your problem by now, but I have never seen that before and I can't find it on the support page. You might want to look and see if you can find anything more specific on the support page (http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/home) and if not, I would submit a request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can skip the loop by just doing this

```
hittingRects = rects.Where(ex => ex != exclude && ex.Touch(edgeToCheck)).ToList();
```